Multiplying and dividing binary data
So in school today we were learning about Binary shifts to the LSL#$n$ and RSL#$n$, where $n$ is an integer.
I shifted a binary number to the left using the logical shift operation, hence multiplying its equivalence decimal number.
I shifted the binary number by $2$ to the left-hand side, hence I multiplied its decimal equivalence by the factor of $2^2$.
Hence, after multiple different examples obtained a specific pattern, that every time I shifted to the left by a certain integer n, I was actually multiplying its decimal equivalence by $2^n$.
I do indeed have a few questions for which I tried to use AI to answer, but wasn't getting a satisfying answer, so I am hoping one of you smart computer scientists can help me.
Firstly I noticed that binary shifts since it's to the power of $2$, it is impossible to obtain an odd number, so how does the CPU multiply number to obtain odd numbers.
Secondly, can the CPU shift the right with decimal phase shifts. Example: shifting by $1.5$ hence multiplying the decimal equivalence by 2^1.5
$Edit:$
So my second question was what does the computer's CPU do to multiply decimal numbers, for example taking the binary number and multiplying it by $0.6123$ which if you equate the number to 2n where $n=log_2 0.6123$ which is also a decimal number. Says that you need to shift the binary number to the left by $n$ to multiply its decimal equivalence by $0.6123$.
How does the CPU overcome this issue?
If this is not true, how else does the CPU obtain answers to these types of problems.
I used AI to solve it at this point, but it said the CPU uses programmed software to be able to multiply these numbers, however is it not true at the basics the software use machine code$?$
Shifting by decimal phase seems very abstract, but still possible.
$Edit:$ first question has been answered
So my first question was what if you want to multiply the binary number by $3$. So essentially you need to shift the binary number by a certain number to obtain the resultant value, I can do this by equating $3$ to $2^n$ where $n$ is $log_2 3$, which is a decimal number, which is not possible, you suggested that computers use shift-add-algothrims, which is correct.

What exactly is your question? I am having a hard time understanding what is your question.  I see only one sentence that ends with a "?", but it seems to be phrased as a declarative sentence.  Also, it contains many phrases, and the structure of it is unclear.  Can you [edit] your post to make it clearer what exactly your question is?  Please ask only one question, and please use grammatically correct English.  Normally a question ends with a "?".

Is it better now?

Please ask one question per post :)

Please don't use "Edit:". Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, with ideas introduced in a logical order.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

Suppose you want to multiply a number $n$ by $5$. You first create a copy of $n$. Now you left shift $n$ two times and then add original $n$ to that.
See the shift-and-add algorithms for the multiplication. Here is one reference.

Computing for an arbitrary exponent is bit tricky. The simplest way you can think of is to use the binomial expansion of the term $(1+a)^n$. This involves some addition and multiplication of real (float) values. The complexity of this route depends on the desired accuracy, which translates into the number of terms of the expansion that you need to calculate.
If you really want to get into the exact details of how the pow() function is implemented in C or how to do the same in a microprocessor, you may see these discussions: pow in C, x86 computation of pow.

Thank you, although for my second question you cannot use shift and add algothrims. As this only applies for integers. when a binary data is multiplied its shifted to the left hence its denary data is obtained for real integers. However if you are to introduce decimal numbers it would be different, for example shifting 0110 000 to the left by a factor of 1.5 is not possible, but multipling the denary equalivance by 2^1.5 is, then how does the CPU calculate decimal numbers if not this way?

And why does this way not work?

To me, it does not make any sense to shift $1.5$ places. Probably what you want is to know how computers compute a value such as $2^{1.5}$. Please see the updated answer.

Ok, the way the CPU multiplies denary numbers is converting them to binary then shifting them to the left, frist shifting the binary number to the left $1$ space multiplies the denary number by $2$. You can try that out. Trying out many of these results in a very visible pattern. where shifting the binary number by $n$ spaces results in its equivilant denary being multiplied by the factor of $2^n$.

So my frist question was what if you want to multiply the binary number by 3. So esstentially you need to shift the binary number by a certain number to obtain the resultant value, I can do this by equating $3$ to $2^n$, where $n$ is $log_2 3$, which is a decimal number, which is not possible, you suggested that computers use shift-add-algothrims, which is correct, and thank you for that

Happy to help :)

So my second question was what does the computers CPU do to multiply decimal numbers, for example taking the binary number and multiplying it by $0.6123$, which if you equate the number to $2^n$, where $n=log_2 0.6123$, which is also a decimal number. Says that you need to shift the binary number to the left by $n$ to multiply its denary equivilance by $0.6123$, how does the CPu overcome this issue$?$
